# Fill row values to the right of some value

Tags: r

Given the following data frame, I need to be able to fill out values in each row to the right until the next value is encountered in which case I need to fill that value out etc. until I reach the end of the row.

```
# load data
id <- LETTERS[1:7]
X2000 <-  c(NA,NA,NA,NA,100,NA,NA)
X2001 <- c(NA,200,80,NA,205,50,NA)
X2002 <- c(NA,300,NA,300,NA,NA,NA)
X2003 <- c(400,NA,70,NA,NA,NA,600)
X2004 <- c(NA,500,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
dat <- data.frame(id,X2000,X2001,X2002,X2003,X2004)

id X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 X2004
A    NA    NA    NA   400    NA
B    NA   200   300    NA   500
C    NA    80    NA    70    NA
D    NA    NA   300    NA    NA
E   100   205    NA    NA    NA
F    NA    50    NA    NA    NA
G    NA    NA    NA   600    NA
```

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
id X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 X2004
A    NA    NA    NA   400   400
B    NA   200   300   300   500
C    NA    80    80    70    70
D    NA    NA   300   300   300
E   100   205   205   205   205
F    NA    50    50    50    50
G    NA    NA    NA   600   600
```

Any clever way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: [Related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20na.locf). `cbind(dat[1], t(zoo::na.locf(t(dat[-1]))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way with `dplyr` and `tidyr` -

```
dat %>%
  gather(year, value, -id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, year) %>% 
  fill(value, .direction = "down") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(year, value)

# A tibble: 7 x 6
  id    X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 X2004
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        NA  NA    NA   400   400  
2 B        NA 200   300   300   500  
3 C        NA  80.0  80.0  70.0  70.0
4 D        NA  NA   300   300   300  
5 E       100 205   205   205   205  
6 F        NA  50.0  50.0  50.0  50.0
7 G        NA  NA    NA   600   600
```

Comment: This was perfect

Answer (score 1):

We could `apply` with `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
dat[-1] <- t(apply(dat[-1], 1, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE))
dat
#   id X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 X2004
#1  A    NA    NA    NA   400   400
#2  B    NA   200   300   300   500
#3  C    NA    80    80    70    70
#4  D    NA    NA   300   300   300
#5  E   100   205   205   205   205
#6  F    NA    50    50    50    50
#7  G    NA    NA    NA   600   600
```

Comment: Note that we can use `na.locf0` which defaults to `na.rm=FALSE` .